# Panel networking menu disabled

Tags: networking, wireless, indicator, notification-area

Roughly every 2 weeks (give or take a few days), my WiFi becomes disconnected and the networking menu becomes disabled.

[image]

I’ve been experiencing this for a few months now hoping I could track down what is causing this to happen. From what I can tell, there is no common events that lead into this menu becoming disabled.

I do have a workaround. To get reconnected I need to go to *System Settings* -> *Networking*. From there, if I turn on **Airplane Mode**, leave it on for a few seconds, then turn it back off. After doing that the Menu Bar Networking menu becomes enabled again and my WiFi automatically reconnects.

While that works, it’s obviously not ideal. Do you have any ideas as to what may be causing this and what may fix this issue?

#### System Details

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (64-bit)
- Computer is a Toshiba Satellite `P875-S7200` (stock)
- Output from script mentioned in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611778/menu-bar-networking-menu-disabled#comment860403_611778) is available on [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/gMagicScott/43dc3796cdc2951ebfb0)

Comment: Here's how to gather some data [using a script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=13024222#post13024222) from the ubuntuforums.org.

Comment: Re: @GrantBowman: I ran that script and the output is available [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/gMagicScott/43dc3796cdc2951ebfb0#file-wireless-info-txt)

Comment: When you ran that it was working? Everything looks enabled. This is a good baseline. Now if you run it again when it's not working you can look for differences, right? Looks like you are using: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200. Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi on interface wlan0. If we can narrow down the workaround to a particular software piece we can find the root cause. Oh, the dmesg does have the errors! `[208143.703437] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC C-01 lesovic_home> (Reason: 7)` Virtualbox shouldn't be at fault. `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` is worth a try. I will google

Comment: Re: @GrantBowman: Usually this error only happens every few weeks, but it happened again today.

When I re-ran the script, at some point during execution, WiFi re-enabled itself. I [updated the gist](https://gist.github.com/gMagicScott/43dc3796cdc2951ebfb0/revisions) with the new output. It looks like 140 new lines of dmesg errors.